# Gamepad hot plugging does not work

Tags: macos, sdl-2, gamepad

In OS X my gamepads are recognised correctly in `SDL_PollEvent()` at application startup. However, when I try hot plugging new gamepads or removing old gamepads, the `SDL_PollEvent()` does not trigger either `SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEADDED` or `SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEREMOVED`. The same code works correctly in Windows when I hot plug game controllers.

A more interesting note is that if I resize the window of my application, the hot plugging works. After resize event all the hot plugging events are triggered. It almost seems that the gamepad events are put in a some kind of waiting queue which is purged when the resize event happens. My `SDL_PollEvent()` code is quite standard as seen below.

```
case SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEADDED:
        if (SDL_IsGameController(e.cdevice.which))
        {
            SDL_GameController *pad = SDL_GameControllerOpen(e.cdevice.which);

            if (pad)
            {
                SDL_Joystick *joy = SDL_GameControllerGetJoystick(pad);
                int instanceID = SDL_JoystickInstanceID(joy);
                if(m_gameControllers.count(instanceID) == 0)
                {
                    m_gameControllers.insert(std::make_pair(instanceID, pad));
                }
            }
        }
    break;

    case SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEREMOVED:
    {
        auto it = m_gameControllers.find(e.cdevice.which);
        if (it != m_gameControllers.end())
        {
            SDL_GameController* pad = m_gameControllers[e.cdevice.which];
            SDL_GameControllerClose(pad);
            m_gameControllers.erase(it);
        }
    }
    break;
```

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some struggling I found the solution: Call `SDL_PollEvent()` from the main thread. Initially I called the gamepad handling method from the CVDisplayLink thread which resulted the described behaviour.

In my case the solution was simply to add `dispatch_async` call to my gamepad handling function.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ { handleGamePad();});
```